# csv parser in erlang

Tags: csv, erlang

for my application i have to parse CSV file using Erlang.following is the code which will parse CSV using Erlang:-

```
parse_file(Fn) ->
{ok, Data} = file:read_file(Fn),
parse(binary_to_list(Data)).

parse(Data) -> lists:reverse(parse(Data, [])).

parse([], Acc) -> Acc;
parse(Data, Acc) ->
{Line, Tail} = parse_line(Data),
parse(Tail, [Line|Acc]).

parse_line(Data) ->
{Line, Tail} = parse_line(Data, []),
{lists:reverse(Line), Tail}.

parse_line([13,10|Data], Acc) -> {Acc, Data};
parse_line([10|Data], Acc) -> {Acc, Data};
parse_line([13|Data], Acc) -> {Acc, Data};
parse_line([], Acc) -> {Acc, []};
parse_line([$,,$,|Data], Acc) -> parse_line(Data, [""|Acc]);
parse_line([$,|Data], Acc) -> parse_line(Data, Acc);
parse_line(Data, Acc) ->
{Fld, Tail} = parse_field(Data),
parse_line(Tail, [Fld|Acc]).

parse_field([34|Data]) ->
{Fld, Tail} = parse_fieldq(Data, ""),
{lists:reverse(Fld), Tail};
parse_field(Data) ->
{Fld, Tail} = parse_field(Data, ""),
{lists:reverse(Fld), Tail}.

parse_field([$,|Tail], Acc) -> {Acc, [$,|Tail]};
parse_field([13|Tail], Acc) -> {Acc, [13|Tail]};
parse_field([10|Tail], Acc) -> {Acc, [10|Tail]};
parse_field([], Acc) -> {Acc, []};
parse_field([Ch|Tail], Acc) -> parse_field(Tail, [Ch|Acc]).

parse_fieldq([34,34|Tail], Acc) -> parse_fieldq(Tail, [34|Acc]);
parse_fieldq([34|Tail], Acc) -> {Acc, Tail};
parse_fieldq([Ch|Tail], Acc) -> parse_fieldq(Tail, [Ch|Acc]).
```

this code works fine but having two issues:-
1-since the code parse using double quote ("") and comma(,) and separate each value..but in following example if First name consist of double quote sting within it then the parser will create one more field.

```
"Type","First Name","Last Name","Email"
"Contact","Ashwani  Garg ------"All Pain Will End."","","itisashwani4u@gmail.com"

result:-
[["contact"],["Ashwani  Garg ------"],["All Pain Will End."],[],["itisashwani4u@gmail.com"]]

expected result:-
[["contact"],["Ashwani  Garg ------All Pain Will End."],[],["itisashwani4u@gmail.com"]]
```

2-for the following kind of csv its for value,its truncate some value:-
First Name,Last Name,Middle Name,Name,Nickname,E-mail Address,Home Street,Home City,Home Postal Code,Home State,Home Country/Region,Home Phone,Home Fax,Mobile Phone,Personal Web Page,Business Street,Business City,Business Postal Code,Business State,Business Country/Region,Business Web Page,Business Phone,Business Fax,Pager,Company,Job Title,Department,Office Location,Notes

```
    Affection,,,Affection,,,,,,,,+919845141544,,+919845141544,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
    result:-
    [["Affection"],[],[],["Affection"],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],["+919845141544"],[],["+919845141544"],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
    expected result:-
   [["Affection"],[],[],["Affection"],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],["+919845141544"],[],["+919845141544"],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
```

Please help me ...for refernce please use the following link:-
  http://ppolv.wordpress.com/2008/02/25/parsing-csv-in-erlang/

Comment: https://github.com/rcouch/ecsv

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
parse(File) ->
  {ok, F} = file:open(File, [read, raw]),
  parse(F, file:read_line(F), []).

parse(F, eof, Done) ->
  file:close(F),
  lists:reverse(Done);    

parse(F, Line, Done) ->
  parse(F, file:read_line(F), [parse_line(Line)|Done]).



parse_line(Line) -> parse_line(Line, []).

parse_line([], Fields) -> lists:reverse(Fields);
parse_line("," ++ Line, Fields) -> parse_field(Line, Fields);
parse_line(Line, Fields) -> parse_field(Line, Fields).

parse_field("\"" ++ Line, Fields) -> parse_field_q(Line, [], Fields);
parse_field(Line, Fields) -> parse_field(Line, [], Fields).

parse_field("," ++ _ = Line, Buf, Fields) -> parse_line(Line, [lists:reverse(Buf)|Fields]);
parse_field([C|Line], Buf, Fields) -> parse_field(Line, [C|Buf], Fields);
parse_field([], Buf, Fields) -> parse_line([], [lists:reverse(Buf)|Fields]).

parse_field_q(Line, Fields) -> parse_field_q(Line, [], Fields).
parse_field_q("\"\"" ++ Line, Buf, Fields) -> parse_field_q(Line, [$"|Buf], Fields);
parse_field_q("\"" ++ Line, Buf, Fields) -> parse_line(Line, [lists:reverse(Buf)|Fields]);
parse_field_q([C|Line], Buf, Fields) -> parse_field_q(Line, [C|Buf], Fields).
```

without file:read_line :

```
parse_file(File) ->
  {ok, Data} = file:read_file(File),
  parse(binary_to_list(Data), []).

parse([], Done) ->
  lists:reverse(Done);

parse(Data, Done) ->
  {Line, Rest} = case re:split(Data, "\r|\n|\r\n", [{return, list}, {parts, 2}]) of
                   [L,R] -> {L,R};
                   [L]   -> {L,[]}
                 end,
  parse(Rest, [parse_line(Line)|Done]).
```

Comment: thanx for your reply..i have run your script..it works well and sort also but check the ouput..
[["Type","First Name","Last Name","Email"],
 [[]],
 ["Contact","null",[],"ashishmichael@gmail.com"],
 [[]]

but you can see there is one [[]] box in every records that is not of any use can we avoid that...

Comment: ** exception error: undefined function file:read_line/1
     in function  csv_erl_parser:parse/1

Comment: OK, I added code to read whole file to memory and work from there. parse_line is the same as before.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand what you mean... do you have double newlines in your file, or what?

Comment: Filtered = [E || E <- P, P =/= [[]]]. You can filter the [[]]'s from the result like this.

Comment: hi Zed, if a field name consits od value with comma saparater like "abhimanyu,singh" then it will parse this values as two list..but it is one value only...

Answer (score 2):

A side issue:

How are you creating the CSV input? It doesn't appear to be valid CSV (not that there is a particularly rigorous specification for CSV though).

Typically to use double quotes inside a CSV field they need to be escaped as a pair of double quotes, so your example would be:

```
"Type","First Name","Last Name","Email"
"Contact","Ashwani  Garg ------""All Pain Will End.""","","itisashwani4u@gmail.com"
```

This will import fine into open office spreadsheet, whereas your original example does not.

Answer (score 2):

I came across your implementation the other day and started playing around with it.

I made you a parser as well.

```
-module(csv_parser).

-export([parse_file/1]).

parse_file(File) ->
  {ok, Data} = file:read_file(File),
  parse(Data).

parse(Data) ->
    Lines = re:split(Data, "\r|\n|\r\n", [] ), 
    [ [begin
           case  re:split(Token, "\"", [] ) of 
               [_,T,_] -> T;
               [T] -> T; % if token is not surrounded by ""
               [] -> <<"">>
           end
       end || Token <- re:split(Line, ",", [] ) ] || Line <- Lines, Line =/= <<"">>].
```

I even wrote a small blogpost on this [csv parser](http://highspeederlang.wordpress.com/)

Comment: Fixed bug: Script failed on nested quotes. <<"a\"\"b\"\"c">>. Now Token is a line WITHOUT Quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Reading lines from a file was also discussed in [Trapexit](http://www.trapexit.org). It should be trivial to adapt that to your needs:

http://www.trapexit.org/Reading_Lines_from_a_File

Comment: The first URL seems to be the same as the one at the end of the question ;)

Answer (score 1):

My implementation:

```
-module(csv).

-export([
    parse/1
]).

parse(File) ->
    try
        {ok, Bin} = file:read_file(File),
        {ok, parse(binary_to_list(Bin), [], [], [])}
    catch
        Class:Error ->
            {Class, Error}
    end.

parse([], _FBuff, _RBuff, Result) ->
    lists:reverse(Result);
parse([$" | Rest], _FBuff, RBuff, Result) ->
    {F, Rest1} = parse_q(Rest, []),
    parse(Rest1, [], [F | RBuff], Result);
parse([$,, $\s| Rest], FBuff, RBuff, Result) ->
    parse(Rest, [], [lists:reverse(FBuff) | RBuff], Result);    
parse([$, | Rest], FBuff, RBuff, Result) ->
    parse(Rest, [], [lists:reverse(FBuff) | RBuff], Result);
parse([$\r, $\n | Rest], _FBuff, RBuff, Result) ->
    parse(Rest, [], [], [lists:reverse(RBuff) | Result]);
parse([$\n | Rest], _FBuff, RBuff, Result) ->
    parse(Rest, [], [], [lists:reverse(RBuff) | Result]);
parse([A | Rest], FBuff, RBuff, Result) ->
    parse(Rest, [A | FBuff], RBuff, Result).

parse_q([$", $, | Rest], Result) ->
    {lists:reverse(Result), Rest};
parse_q([A | Rest], Result) ->
    parse_q(Rest, [A | Result]).
```

However, this solution can't deal with the nested quotes...

For example:

1, "Hello, "World"", "She says:"It's "the" solution, isn't it?"", 2000\r\n

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution. Can be easily changed to lazy evaluation so reading whole file at once is not necessary.

```
parse(Data) -> parse(Data, [], [], []).

parse([$\r|Data], Field, Fields, Lines) -> parse_r(Data, Field, Fields, Lines);
parse([$\n|Data], Field, Fields, Lines) -> parse(Data, [], [], [[Field|Fields]|Lines]);
parse([$,|Data], Field, Fields, Lines)  -> parse(Data, [], [Field|Fields], Lines);
parse([$"|Data], [], Fields, Lines)     -> parse_q(Data, [], Fields, Lines);
parse([C|Data], Field, Fields, Lines)   -> parse(Data, [C|Field], Fields, Lines);
parse([], Field, Fields, Lines)         -> 
  lists:reverse(
      [lists:reverse(
          [lists:reverse(F) || F <- L]
        ) || L <- [[Field|Fields]|Lines]]
    ).

parse_r([$\n|_] = Data, Field, Fields, Lines) -> parse(Data, Field, Fields, Lines).

parse_q([$"|Data], Field, Fields, Lines) -> parse_qq(Data, Field, Fields, Lines);
parse_q([C|Data], Field, Fields, Lines)  -> parse_q(Data, [C|Field], Fields, Lines).

parse_qq([$"|Data], Field, Fields, Lines) -> parse_q(Data, [$"|Field], Fields, Lines);
parse_qq([C|_] = Data, Field, Fields, Lines)  
  when C == $,; C == $\r; C == $\n        -> parse(Data, Field, Fields, Lines);
parse_qq([], Field, Fields, Lines)        -> parse([], Field, Fields, Lines).
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added couple of enhancements to the zed's answer.

```
-module (helper_csv_parser).
-compile(export_all).

% Taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532081/csv-parser-in-erlang, modified to fix errors.
parse(File) ->
    {ok, F} = file:open(File, [read, {encoding, utf8}]),
    {ok, L} = file:read_line(F),
    parse(F, string:strip(L, right, $\n), [], 1).

parse(F, eof, Done, _) ->
    file:close(F),
    lists:reverse(Done);

parse(F, Line, Done, Ctr) ->
    Res = file:read_line(F),

    case Res of
        {error,collect_line} -> throw({error, "Might be unicode at line " ++ helper:i2s(Ctr)});
        {ok, L} -> parse(F, string:strip(L, right, $\n),[parse_line(Line)|Done], Ctr+1);
        eof -> parse(F,eof,[parse_line(Line)|Done], Ctr+1)
    end.

parse_line("," ++ Line) -> parse_line(Line, [[]]);
parse_line(Line) -> parse_line(Line, []).

parse_line([], Fields) -> lists:reverse(Fields);
parse_line("," ++ Line, Fields) -> parse_field(Line, Fields);
parse_line(Line, Fields) -> parse_field(Line, Fields).

parse_field("\"" ++ Line, Fields) -> parse_field_q(Line, [], Fields);
parse_field(Line, Fields) -> parse_field(Line, [], Fields).

parse_field("," ++ _ = Line, Buf, Fields) -> parse_line(Line, [string:strip(lists:reverse(Buf))|Fields]);
parse_field([C|Line], Buf, Fields) -> parse_field(Line, [C|Buf], Fields);
parse_field([], Buf, Fields) -> parse_line([], [lists:reverse(Buf)|Fields]).

parse_field_q(Line, Fields) -> parse_field_q(Line, [], Fields).
parse_field_q("\"\"" ++ Line, Buf, Fields) -> parse_field_q(Line, [$"|Buf], Fields);
parse_field_q("\"" ++ Line, Buf, Fields) -> parse_line(Line, [string:strip(lists:reverse(Buf))|Fields]);
parse_field_q([C|Line], Buf, Fields) -> parse_field_q(Line, [C|Buf], Fields).
```

Answer (score 0):

Wisher's answer isn't bad, except it loses the last element of every csv line. Here's fix for that. It still does not deal with embedded quotes though.

```
-module(csv).

-export([read/1]).

read(File) ->
    try
        {ok, Bin} = file:read_file(File),
        {ok, parse(binary_to_list(Bin), [], [], [])}
    catch
        Class:Error ->
            {Class, Error}
    end.

parse([], _FBuff, _RBuff, Result) ->
    lists:reverse(Result);
parse([$" | Rest], _FBuff, RBuff, Result) ->
    {F, Rest1} = parse_q(Rest, []),
    parse(Rest1, [], [F | RBuff], Result);
parse([$,, $\s| Rest], FBuff, RBuff, Result) ->
    parse(Rest, [], [lists:reverse(FBuff) | RBuff], Result);
parse([$, | Rest], FBuff, RBuff, Result) ->
    parse(Rest, [], [lists:reverse(FBuff) | RBuff], Result);
parse([$\r, $\n | Rest], FBuff, RBuff, Result) ->
    parse(Rest, [], [], [lists:reverse([lists:reverse(FBuff) | RBuff]) | Result]);
parse([$\n | Rest], FBuff, RBuff, Result) ->
    parse(Rest, [], [], [lists:reverse([lists:reverse(FBuff) | RBuff]) | Result]);
parse([A | Rest], FBuff, RBuff, Result) ->
    parse(Rest, [A | FBuff], RBuff, Result).

parse_q([$", $, | Rest], Result) ->
    {lists:reverse(Result), Rest};
parse_q([A | Rest], Result) ->
    parse_q(Rest, [A | Result]).
```